# Multiple markers at this line and Bound mismatch error

Tags: java, android, robotium

I'm new to Robotium and android.In the belwo code, am getting "Bound mismatch" error.

Bound mismatch: The type Webview_Main is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter  of the type 
 ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2
- Implicit super constructor ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit

```
import com.robotium.solo.Solo;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

public class g_basic extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Webview_Main> {

    private Solo solo;

    public void testPreferenceIsSaved() throws Exception {

        solo.sendKey(Solo.MENU);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see how it should be done on this page:

https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Getting_Started

There is also an example test project you can download from there.